# Broadcast live video on Facebook using Graph API in Android

Tags: java, android, facebook-graph-api, rtmp

I am trying to broadcast live video on Facebook page using Graph API. I login to page with admin account where publish_video, manage_pages and publish_pages permissions are accessible. Then I generate Graph API request to get **RTMP Stream URL** to publish video on Facebook page using LiveVideoBroadcaster SDK but for this essence I need to have page access token first in order to find RTMP stream URL for that page.

I can get the object of access token of a user by calling `AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()` but how can I create an object of **AccessToken** for that page I did not find in docs.

Following is the snippet code for Graph API request which I am using.

```
    LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithPublishPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("publish_video", "manage_pages", "publish_pages"));
    /* AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() // user access token */
    GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newPostRequest({page-access-token},"/" + "{page-id}" + "/live_videos",
                    new JSONObject("{\"title\": \"Today's live video\", \"description\": \"This is the live video for today.\"}"),
                    new GraphRequest.Callback(){
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response){
                            try {
                                 String stream_url = response.getJSONObject().getString("stream_url");
                                } catch (JSONException e){}
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#pagetokens

Answer (score 0):

you can receive page token from Graph API request

...
{page-id}?fields=access_token

then

```
    AccessToken currentAccessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
    AccessToken pageAccessToken = new AccessToken(page_token, currentAccessToken.getApplicationId(), currentAccessToken.getUserId()
            ,currentAccessToken.getPermissions(), currentAccessToken.getDeclinedPermissions(), currentAccessToken.getExpiredPermissions(), currentAccessToken.getSource()
            ,currentAccessToken.getExpires(), currentAccessToken.getLastRefresh(), currentAccessToken.getDataAccessExpirationTime());
```